# Pyspark avoid _corrupt_record column while loading a list of jsons

Tags: python, json, azure, pyspark, databricks

I have a dataframe that loads data from a python list of jsons.

```
df = spark.read\
            .option("inferSchema","true")\
            .option("multiline",True)\
            .json(sc.parallelize(array_json))
```

The json structure can look like this:

```
{
  "name" : "Alex"
  "value" : 2,
  "tag" : {
    "property1" : "value1"
  }
}
```

But also it can look like this:

```
{
  "name" : "Robert"
  "value" : 2,
  "tag" : None
}
```

As you can see, the property **tag** can be a json or a null value.

The problem I'm having is that I'm getting a column called **_corrupt_record** only for the json values that have the tag value as None.

| _corrupt_record | name | value | tag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| null | Alex | 2 | {"property1":"value1"} |
| {"name":"Robert","value":2,"tag":None | null | null | null |

I want the dataframe to be like the following:

| name | value | tag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alex | 2 | {"property1":"value1"} |
| Robert | 2 | None |

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: what about providing explicit schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reproduced this and faced same issue with the JSON data that you have provided.


[image]


[image]


Here, in the above JSON, the None value in not inside any quotes and it may cause the corrupt_record  as it is not any type of int, string etc.

To get the desired dataframe like above, try to provide the **schema of the JSON explicitly** as suggested by **@Alex Ott**.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
schema = StructType([
    StructField("name", StringType(), True),
    StructField("tag", StringType(), True),
    StructField("value", IntegerType(), True)
])

df=spark.createDataFrame(data=myjson,schema=schema)
df.show()
```

If we give the schema explicitly, spark identifies the type before and assigns null values for None.


**OUTPUT:**


[image]


If your JSON is a file, you can try like this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66053285/pyspark-corrupt-record-while-reading-json-file) by [blackbishop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1386551/blackbishop).

Comment: Instead of importing, one can use this schema too: `schema = 'name string, tag string, value int'`

Comment: @ZygD, yeah, we can do like that as well.